# Second screen is not properly recognized

Tags: intel-graphics

[Ubuntu 14.04 64bit]

According to NVIDIA-settings I am currently using the Intel GPU (is there a way to verify that via command-line?).

```
> lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] (rev a1)


> xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      59.9*+
   [...]
   640x480        59.9  

VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+1920+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-1 disconnected
```

VGA1 is plugged in and works more or less - that means it functions as a second screen just that the resolution is very low (it is 1024x768) and the ratio is not correct (it is 4:3). The ratio is actually the bigger issue because I mostly use my large external display for watching movies. Apparently because the ratio is 4:3 instead of 16:9 in full screen mode large parts of the picture is missing.

In the display settings the monitor is shown as "unknown".

What can I do?

I tried upgrading the driver but apparently it is already up-to-date:

```
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
[sudo] password for raffael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version.
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me with Ubuntu, graphic card, screen and all.

Curiously with other screen worked well and sometimes goes back to normal with this one, but goes back at the same fail suddenly, after shutting down and turning on.

Try this with the desired resolution, mine is 1440x900 , IT WORKED for me!!

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
```