# Can't switch to Nvidia GPU from Intel or how to make Nvidia driver work (black screen, freeze login in, errors etc)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xserver

My problem is known, but still remains unsolved. After installing the latest (or any other version) of Nvidia drivers I get black screen or am unable to login.

Useful information:

- `nvidia-detector` shows `none`,
- `lspci` shows:

  ```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
  ```
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 x64
- linux kernel version is `3.13.0-37-generic`
- Nvidia driver version is `340.46`

I can switch (visually) between  via `nvidia-prime` and Nvidia X Server Settings now, though before it was impossible due to different problems like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451335/cant-switch-anymore-from-intel-to-nvidia-gpu).

I've tried to install the latest drivers from official page, but get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only after fresh installing **Ubuntu 14.10** and choosing **Nvidia binary driver - version 331.89 from nvidia-331** (System settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers) many of my problems have solved! Great!

- Nvidia card works now! (after 1 year)
- Correct brightness control
- Laptop have become colder

If the list of additional drives is empty, put a tick on "Canonical Partners" at System settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software, close, update cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall Nvidia and Intel drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* intel* 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoremove intltool*
```

Then install Nvidia and Intel both from control  center/additional Drivers.
Next run terminal and install `prime-indicator` to swith easily.

```
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
sudo reboot
```