# Installing Nvidia 820M graphic Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-prime

I started by installing nvidia-current and nvidia-prime( I have no idea what this is. I read it online somewhere.Please tell me what it is :( ) and typed

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and it gave me this

```
Error: alternatives are not set up properly
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled
```

I googled for the error and based on Michael's advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451335/cant-switch-anymore-from-intel-to-nvidia-gpu) , I typed this( again I have no idea about it).

```
root@PapaGolf:~# sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

[Result Of Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V5Yb.png)

and again tried to switch to nvidia by

```
root@PapaGolf:~# prime-select nvidia
```

Now I'm stuck with

```
Error: %s does not support PRIME power management
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled
```

I googled for this error as well but couldn't get anywhere. Can anyone help?

Edit(Output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D')

```
siera@PapaGolf:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0662
    Kernel driver in use: i915

08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GeForce 820M
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I just edited it as you asked.

Comment: It looks good. How did you install the driver?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I installed nvidia-current. sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: That was wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You installed a wrong driver for your adapter.

`nvidia-current` is a package for legacy cards.

You need to remove it and install the correct one:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

`prime-select` should work after reboot.

These commands will install Nvidia driver version 346 for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04.

For Ubuntu 15.10 the commands will install driver version 352.

Comment: May I ask you how'd you get the driver number 346? I'll try installing it and post the result asap.

Comment: It is the package name for new Nvidia cards Ubuntu 14.04. It will install version 346 for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04. It will automatically install driver version 352 for Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is how did you know that my card would support version 346 and not some other version? Is it mandatory for every 14.04 to install 346 only? :/

Comment: You can find it out by looking into System Settings _> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers. Or just see http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I installed nvidia 346 as you asked and it prime-select worked perfectly. But it seems they aren't the drivers for my device. When I booted it again I saw nothing but black screen. I had to shift to text mode, quit lightdm, uninstall the drivers and boot again. Now I'm where I started from :(    And btw System Settings _> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers shows me nvidia-340!!

Comment: @cl-netbox I rolled back your edit. I wrote what I wrote. It will install 352 deiver to 15.10 with `nvidia-346` command.

Comment: @cl-netbox I revoked some of them. But does it matter that much? It was always peace. You can ping me in chat.

Answer (score -1):

use this in you terminal to install nvidia GPU
`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`

Comment: I read it on nvidia's website that linux headers are required to install legacy drivers and mine is not one of those and furthermore, after all this testing my current problem is to find current version of drivers( or so do i suppose ).  Can you tell me about that?