# No login screen after boot screen on installaion of NVIDIA drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an NVIDIA 820M graphic adapter for which I tried installing `nvidia-352` drivers. `prime-select query` keeps showing unknown and I cannot switch my drivers as it says that alternatives are not set up properly. I referred [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451335/cant-switch-anymore-from-intel-to-nvidia-gpu) link to set the alternatives and was successfully able to switch but as soon as I reboot the system I do not get my login screen but a black screen after boot screen.

For some reason  System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers only displays nvidia-340 on my laptop even after update. So I tried installing nvidia 340 as well and the results were same as described above.

Answer (score 1):

#### Install the NVIDIA drivers and NVIDIA Optimus (PRIME) in a different way :

#### 1. Remove all NVIDIA software you tried to install before.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password ... then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

#### 2. Install NVIDIA drivers 352 from the Ubuntu repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password ... then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

#### Update addressing your feedback that it still doesn't work with drivers 352 :

#### 1. Remove the currently installed NVIDIA 352 drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password ... then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

#### 2. Install the latest official stable NVIDIA 361 drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password ... then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: well, It's same as installing NVIDIA drivers when your system is up and running and then reboot. Isn't it? What's the difference? @cl-netbox

Comment: @7_R3X : No ... it is quite different ... the open source nouveau drivers, which can generate compatibility issues are deactivated during the whole complete NVIDIA drivers uninstallation and installation process. :)

Comment: Tried it your way but it's still the same. It seems like the display turns off after the boot screen. @cl-netbox