# Gnome dependency problems with Nvidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, gnome, dependencies

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I once installed the nvidia drivers (`nvidia-355`) and then after a few days I installed Gnome 3.10. It kept complaining about some dependency problem so I figured it'd be something that I perhaps made a mistake with. Then recently, on a fresh install, I installed Gnome first and then installed Nvidia drivers. Now every time I open Nvidia settings and try to switch to the Nivida graphics card other than the integrated Intel card (yes its on a laptop), I get this error message similar to the one shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451335/cant-switch-anymore-from-intel-to-nvidia-gpu). In fact, its the exact same error. Now the funny part is, if I uninstall gnome, I'm able to use the nvidia card. But when I reinstall it back using `gnome-shell`, the same problem pops up again. Perhaps some help on finding the package which has the dependency problem and fixing it?

P.S I do remember it had something to do with two different versions of the same package being required by both of them, not sure though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I'm not sure what exactly was the problem, but this issue seems to have disappeared on a fresh install of 16.04. Perhaps they updated the dependencies properly in it? I'm not sure. But I can personally confirm that this is no longer an issue in 16.04