# Ubuntu 16.04 - Issue with NVIDIA graphics after updating kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, xorg

I upgraded my Linux kernel from 4.4 to 4.6 but after that I began having problems with my display drivers. Some black boxes are appearing around every dialog box I open.

[ImageScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4eVR.jpg)

The blackbox in the above image appears when I open the terminal. I am not able to do anything?

I tried to reinstall my proprietary nvidia driver(340) but that didnt help either. I followed instructions from this post. [Can't Switch anymore from Intel to Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451335/cant-switch-anymore-from-intel-to-nvidia-gpu)

I used `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf` and selecte the one with the `nvidia-prime` but when I restarted my Laptop it gets reverted back to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/l.so.conf`

Is there some way to fix this without having to return back to kernel 4.4 as I my FPS is very low with this kernel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to an unsupported kernel.

Comment: Is 4.6.0 unsupported kernel?

Comment: Anything but 3.13 and 4.4 is unsupported now.

Comment: But  I upgraded my kernel so question is also about whether I should revert back to 4.4.x because my fps sucks in 4.4.x?

Comment: @Pilot OP has a good point. The question does ask if he should use a supported kernel with drawbacks. Could we suggest trying 3.13 to increase speed? I'm not sure of the side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which 4.6 Kernel. eg 4.6.3 Kernel fixed numerous Dell ACPI issues according to documentation if memory serves me correctly. You should know specifically which kernel version solves your FPS (frames per second) issues before upgrading.

Besides this 4.6.x series is already at EOL (End of Life) and you should go with 4.7.5 unless it is known to be broken with Nvidia.

In Ubuntu you can get more up-to-date Nvidia drivers (than your #340) from `System Settings`, `Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers`:

[image: Additional Drivers]

Going to this screen first is probably your best bet with Ubuntu 16.04. Many of these drivers are tested by the Ubuntu team which may not be a 100% guarantee does offer greater peace of mind. I'm not sure why the Nvidia drivers are listed as `open source` because last time I looked they were marked as `proprietary`.

You should update your question with your Nvidia card model, your computer make and model and the exact kernel version you are running (output of `uname -a`).

I suggest installing and using kernel version 4.7.5 instead of 4.6.x. Bear in mind that kernel version 4.8 will be here soon and support for 4.7.x series may end soon after. Linux Kernel 4.9 will be the next LTS (Long Term Support) version.

### Edit 1 - Tried Nvidia Driver 367.44 on my laptop

After posting the answer I went back into `Additional Drivers` and the Nvidia drivers were in a different order with `367.44` at the bottom. I clicked the `Apply` button and it took about 5 minutes to install the drivers. Then I clicked the `Restart` button.

Upon boot I got a **blank screen** with a frozen cursor at the top. Apparently it happened to lots of others and the solution is to reboot and enter `e` in the grub menu. Find the line with "quiet splash" and add the parameter `nomodeset` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting.

Then up comes the famous low resolution 640x480? login screen that prompts you for your password in an endless loop. So press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for the console login screen. Then type:

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo reboot
```

Now the system is back to using HD4000 Intel Integrated Graphics and I've successfully installed Nvidia for the first time in the 2+ years of owning this laptop. Granted the first thing I did was turn Nvidia off!

If this happens to you, people recommend going to the Nvidia website.

---

### Edit 2 - Upgrade Kernel and other Intel tips

The OP commented Kernel 4.6.0 is being used so an upgrade to 4.7.5 should be done. How to upgrade the kerenl is described in an answer I wrote to another Intel question: [Ubuntu 15.10: Various "types" of freezes and now unexpected shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827939/ubuntu-15-10-various-types-of-freezes-and-now-unexpected-shutdown). Also included in this answer are helpful (for me and hopefully for you) tips on:

- Intel Microcode
- Intel cstate
- Intel pstate
- Update your Linux Kernel version Optional
- Disable Intel Turbo Boost overheating

As always, please post a follow-up comment on what works / doesn't work.

---

### Edit 3 - Add Nvidia repositories before selecting driver

Unconfirmed answer from: [Install Nvidia driver instead nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau) suggests you first run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Which starts out with this information screen:

```
 Fresh drivers from upstream, currently shipping Nvidia.

## Current Status

Current official release: `nvidia-370` (370.28)
Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-367` (367.44)

For GeForce 8 and 9 series GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.98)
For GeForce 6 and 7 series GPUs use `nvidia-304` (304.132)

## What we're working on right now:

- Normal driver updates
- Investigating how to bring this goodness to distro on a cadence.

## WARNINGS:

This PPA is currently in testing, you should be experienced with packaging before you dive in here. Give us a few days to sort out the kinks.

Volunteers welcome! See also: https://github.com/mamarley/nvidia-graphics-drivers/
```

For my Nvdidia Geforce GT650M it recommends `304` driver. Therefore installing 367 may have been a mistake for my platform.

After adding Nvidia repository the linked answer says to run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it is working fine with Intel Drivers but how should I switch to Nvidia without having this problem? With my case in Additional Drivers it is only giving me 340. My graphics card is Nvidia GT 720M and kernel version is 4.6.0.  Laptop is of Lenovo. Should I upgrade my kernel to 4.7.x?
PS: No login loop in my case. It's working fine.

Comment: @jstraj I added `Edit 2` section. Unfortunately I don't know why your `Additional Drivers` section is only showing Nvidia version `340`. Perhaps the Nvidia installed drivers have to be removed before all driver versions will appear? After selecting and installing `367.44` on my system all the drivers disappeared and the section no longer appears in `Additional Drivers`.

Comment: Well, i tried all the things you said but the thing never works! I upgraded my kernel. But when I completely reverted back my Kernel to 4.4.0-42 it worked fine. Fine as in same old low fps which is around 30-40. Seems i have to live with that till some update comes.
I am really sorry for such a late reply as I was out of town.