# Installed new graphics card, broke my drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

I recently installed a new GTX 1070 alongside my old R9 290X.
When I rebooted the system I get put into low graphics mode. I know that amd and Nvidia drivers don't work on the same system, but I thought I would still be able to boot.

I tried to run the fix option which did nothing. Attempting to continue booting in low graphics mode causes the screens to go black. I can boot to the login menu from grub "safe mode" but attempting to log in keeps kicking me back to the login screen.

I am running the open source radeon drivers on my AMD card and Ubuntu 14.04.5.

EDIT:Like an idiot i forgot the question part of my question.
I was wondering if there is some way to force Ubuntu to ignore the new GPU, I want to use it for a PCI pass through VM, so I dont really need Ubuntu to use it.

Comment: ...and what's the question?

Comment: Ah, I knew I forgot something important.  Added the question now.

Comment: I was in a similar spot last night. Read the bottom of the answer to see it helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/831352/ubuntu-16-04-issue-with-nvidia-graphics-after-updating-kernel/831376?noredirect=1#comment1267504_831376]

Comment: After pressing e in the GRUB menu I don't see the quiet splash line. I may have removed it a while back while working on another problem and just left it out becaus having the grub screen there automatically has proven handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by running `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` in tty2 
(`Ctrl+Alt+f2`). In retrospect I probably should have tried this sooner.