# libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

After the installation of any programs I get the following error

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

What is this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: It is a bug reported by most users. Try installing driver software  http://askubuntu.com/questions/851069/latest-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04 and let us know if resolved

Comment: Found a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1662860

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is an issue which has affected many users and is 
[reported as a bug at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1662860).

There appears to be a conflict between different versions of libEGL.

To get rid of these warning, create the following symlinks (but first read the **warning** bellow):

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1.org
sudo mv /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1.org
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.375.39 /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.375.39 /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1
```

**Warning**: There is no need to change your system. If after reboot you can not start the graphical interface you can solve by:
1. Login into a terminal;
2. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia*`

Comment: As Noisy_Botnet mentioned (sorry, can't comment underneath there due to rep points) or as discussed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1662860?comments=all) the problem could be resolved TEMPORARILY. But now that the driver version upgraded from 375.39 to 375.51, you may have to repeat it with '39's replaced with '51's this time... And for future, you may have to check the versions (when 375.51 is upgraded) and the link I gave for updates on the issue... P.S: Read until the end before actually typing the commands on the link; some of the command l

Comment: any word on a real fix for this?

Comment: Does this solution need to be repeated on every version upgrade?

Comment: I seem to find myself doing this more than once per system and as mentioned in an earlier comment, I needed to change the numbers.

Comment: I think this is what bricked my system forcing a nuke-n-pave.  Prior to that I had upgraded from 15.10 and KDE sddm-greeter kept crashing with a segfault in the same EGL library, so also did gdm.  When I reverted to Nouveau, it worked but it was incredibly low FPS (we're talking video circa 1990 slow).  This is a significant issue, I've already lost 10 hours today over this.

Comment: I needed to perform these steps when I got the next upgrade, today.  And, as @hekimgil pointed out, the numbers have rolled on.  Worked fine on my 2014 MacBook Pro running 16.04.2.

Comment: The steps above (just the moving and symlinking, not even the reconfigure) solved the problem I was having on my system.  I was getting the same error messages (with a different nvidia-VERSION), and the end result is that my laptop, which has an internal intel and NVIDIA graphics card, was only loading the intel card, resulting in my external monitors not working.  Making these symlinks again and restarting fixed it!

Answer (score 11):

The following is an easy-to-use version of Noisy_Botnet's solution. It facilitates repeating the process for any update.

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
#
# find the file in /usr/lib
LIBEGL=`find /usr/lib/nvidia* -name libEGL.so.\* | egrep "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$"`
LIBEGL_LINK=`echo $LIBEGL | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$/1/'`
printf "\n\nThe following commands will be executed:\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
printf "mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig\nln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK\n\n"
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to perform these commands?  " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig; ln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK ; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

# find the file in /usr/lib32
LIBEGL=`find /usr/lib32/nvidia* -name libEGL.so.\* | egrep "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$"`
LIBEGL_LINK=`echo $LIBEGL | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$/1/'`
printf "\n\nThe following commands will be executed:\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
printf "mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig\nln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK\n\n"
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to perform these commands?  " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig; ln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK ; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

did you upgrade without update first? I had the same message, I updated, upgraded and the message was gone

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install nvidia-375` and then installed my apps.

Comment: @Dante and it worked? The error disappeared?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.2, the first thing I did was upgrading my system from the main repository. After that I installed `nvidia-375` driver and finally I installed any other applications I needed.  But after the installation of each application I get the error mentioned in my question. So the error didn't disappear. On the contrary, it started to happen after upgrading.

Comment: `update+upgrade` didn't solve the issue for me either :(

Comment: It did work for me (installing sketch).  So I removed sketch, did an update+upgrade, and reinstall sketch

Comment: You probably want to make sure you get a *complete* upgrade.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/79954/11522

Comment: ... Nevermind, I still see the message when installing new packages in 16.04.3.  My system is completely up to date: `sudo apt-get upgrade: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up getting through it; it had worked before.
I have Cuda 8.0 and Tensorflow 1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

This is how I resolved the issue.
First,

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then,

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

It works now. The execution order matters.